# Deploying application to iPhone (error in version)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created the sample test application in VMware Mac OS X with Xcode 4.2. My iPhone model is 3GS. iOS version 3.1.3. I got a problem when I deploy to iPhone. It says iOS 3.1.3 is not supporting like that, so can anyone give idea for this? I dont like to upgrade the iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project and then under "PROJECT" change the iOS deployment target.

[image: Changing the build target version]

Comment: I have iphone apple phone. Its model is 3gs. My version is 3.1.2. I need to upgrade my phone so i just restored the mobile, now my phone is not working. i think my phone is locked.

    Am trying this past two days, but no improvement.
    
    can anyone give idea to unlock my phone. if i unlock my iphone means thats enough. 

    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OS of your xCode is 4.0, while of your phone is 3.1.3.

So you need to do either of these -

1. Upgrade your phone to OS 4.0
2. Install selecting iOS 3 as target

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the deployment target to 3.0 or lower. Then you should be able to install on your device.

It should be noted that if you use any frameworks that are not available in 3.0 the app will crash, unless you weak link the framework and don't use it. So you can't use Game Center or iAd or anything like that on your 3.0 device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your deployment target,try to keep it 3.0.

Comment: I just restored my iphone then now my phone is not working... i dont konw why? can anyone please tell the reason?

Comment: I have iphone apple phone. Its model is 3gs. My version is 3.1.2. I need to upgrade my phone so i just restored the mobile, now my phone is not working. i think my phone is locked.

    Am trying this past two days, but no improvement.